# Seeking JCR compliant client library to access a CMIS repository?

Tags: java, jcr, cmis, apache-chemistry

What is the best Java client library, that implements the standard JCR API, that can access a CMIS repository.  I have a program that talks to JCR, and I would like to make it use a CMIS repository.

Some unsubstantiated claims say that [Apache Chemistry](http://chemistry.apache.org/) can do this.  However, I can't find any clear documentation of this.  There is copious documentation about how Chemistry will allow you to use CMIS to access a JCR repository.

Apache Chemistry offers a [client library](http://chemistry.apache.org/java/developing/guide.html) for accessing CMIS repositories, but this appears to be a non-standard API to do so -- the class and methods names mention CMIS directly.  There is no mention that this client library is JCR compliant.

If you are writing a program that can plug in different repositories, it makes sense to write to use JCR.  This [excellent article](http://dev.day.com/content/ddc/blog/2009/05/jcrcmiscomparison.html) explains how they are compatible.  So, what is the best Java LIB that allows me to write a program to JCR in order to access a CMIS repository?  (Or is there some reason that this is nonsense?)

Comment: Great question! You are right, "OpenCMIS JCR Repository" only does the opposite. Like Randall I thought immediately about ModeShape, but that's overkill indeed... but I don't know any better library as of now.

Comment: I think JCR is dead, actually.  I am probably going to go with the Apache unique API for CMIS, and forget about JCR.

Answer (score 0):

[ModeShape](http://modeshape.org) implements the JCR 2.0 API, and has a feature called [federation](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/MODE/Federation) that allows it to include the content from external systems into an area of the ModeShape repository. ModeShape's [connectors](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/MODE/Federation#Federation-Connectors) translate the external system into nodes and properties. All of this is transparent to client applications, which see just like one JCR repository with nodes and properties - some of those nodes just happen to be owned by ModeShape, while other content happens to be owned by external systems. (Clients actually cannot directly tell the difference between a node owned by ModeShape and one that is a projection of data in an external system. Of course, the external content might have different node types, making it possible for a client to infer what is external versus internal.)

ModeShape 3.2 includes a CMIS connector that supports read and write. However, it's pretty new and may not have all of the features you're looking for. Plus, ModeShape always has at least some of its own content (e.g., the "jcr:system" area), though it's pretty easy to [store that](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/MODE/Clustering) on the local file system, in a database, or even in a data grid.

Comment: I took a look at this, and as you point out, ModeShape is really content management system.  I have a program that IS a content management system, and i don't want to add another content management system to that.  I just need something encapsulates the direct manipulation of objects into the protocol, to browse and fetch files on demand.  Apache Chemistry has a client library, it is just not JCR compliant.  At this point I probably will just go with that ... on the conclusion that JCR is basically unimportant.